# Solana Rust - Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown

Tags: solana-program, rust, failed, smart-contract

I am creating simple contract for storing ipfs hashes (see in attachment). When trying to call instruction 1 (AddIpfsHash) from python via solana-py and solders I get following error:

"Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown"

I have tried multiple things, but i am not quite sure how to go on (i am not Rust developer, this is just for my Master Thesis :D) . If you could provide any help I would be very greatful ! If you'd like to see the code from python I will be happy to share and check it with you.

```
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    program_error::ProgramError,
    rent::Rent,
    sysvar::Sysvar,
    msg
};

// Define the instruction types this program can handle
pub enum Instruction {
    InitializeAccount,
    AddIpfsHash { hash: String },
}

// Struct to represent the IPFS record
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct IpfsRecord {
    pub ipfs_hashes: Vec<String>,
}

// Deserialize instruction data into the Instruction enum
impl Instruction {
    pub fn unpack(input: &[u8]) -> Result<Self, ProgramError> {
        let (&instruction_type, rest) = input.split_first().ok_or(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)?;

        Ok(match instruction_type {
            0 => Self::InitializeAccount,
            1 => {
                let hash = String::from_utf8(rest.to_vec()).map_err(|_| ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)?;
                Self::AddIpfsHash { hash }
            },
            _ => return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData),
        })
    }
}

// Entry point of the program
entrypoint!(process_instruction);

// Program entry function
fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

    if account.owner != program_id {
        msg!("Account does not have the correct program id");
        return Err(ProgramError::IncorrectProgramId);
    }

    let instruction = Instruction::unpack(instruction_data)?;

    match instruction {
        Instruction::InitializeAccount => {
            let rent_exemption = Rent::get()?.minimum_balance(account.data_len());
            if **account.lamports.borrow() < rent_exemption {
                return Err(ProgramError::InsufficientFunds);
            }

            let ipfs_record = IpfsRecord { ipfs_hashes: Vec::new() };
            ipfs_record.serialize(&mut &mut account.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;
        },
        Instruction::AddIpfsHash { hash } => {
            let mut ipfs_record = IpfsRecord::try_from_slice(&account.data.borrow())?;
            ipfs_record.ipfs_hashes.push(hash);
            msg!("Zde");
            ipfs_record.serialize(&mut &mut account.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;
        },
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is most likely getting triggered on this line:

```
let mut ipfs_record = IpfsRecord::try_from_slice(&account.data.borrow())?;
```

Be sure that you've allocated enough space in the account to accommodate many strings using `system_instruction::create_account` first.

You may also be tripping up a length check on the normal `try_from_slice` if the account has a lot of bytes allocated, so you may need to use the `try_from_slice_unchecked` helper at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/aba8ce5f3ef5af4c7241906ccf419e0dd4d7ff69/sdk/program/src/borsh.rs#L195

Comment: Thanks that ```try_from_slice_unchecked```  helped!